# DB::enableQueryLog() return undifiend method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to log query and get it's sql so I tried:

```
DB::enableQueyLog();
        Auth::user()->books();
        dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

but I get error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::enableQueyLog()"

also tried what suggested in laravel 5.8 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#listening-for-query-events) but nothing get output to screen and when I open the log file there is no sql in it.

please how to log the query and get it is raw sql?

**Update:**
I have tried to do the following:

in AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
             $query->sql;
             $query->bindings;
            // $query->time
        });


    }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
 Auth::user()->books();
        dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

now I get:

> []

and no sql command that is executed.

please kindly help me

Comment: `Quey` and `Query` are not the same thing.

Comment: In your update, you haven't enabled the query log. `DB::listen` and `DB::enableQueryLog` aren't the same. If you want to use `DB::listen`, you have to do something with the query you listened for, like log it somewhere. **Just fix the typo in the original post and you'll be fine.**

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled the method name.

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please first enable query log using below code

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

then after you can use below method

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```